# Angular me agrega un # a la ruta

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Querida Comunidad.
Tengo el siguiente problema.
Estuve desarrollando lo mas bien, hasta que quise subir el proyecto de angular a mi servidor, hice el `ng build`, pero no lograba ingresar a la página de inicio. Entonces comencé a jugar con el   `<base href="/">` del index.html y compilaba una y otra vez, además de no lograr que funcione bien en producción, ahora en desarrollo, cuando ejecuto `ng serve` a la pagina de inicio le agrega un `#` si bien, dicha página se muestra, al querer dirigirme a otra ruta, no la muestra, porque obviamente la direcciona sin el `#`.
Si voy al home, se muestra de la siguiente manera:
http://localhost:4200/#/
¿Alguna ayuda para que esto no suceda?
¿Qué archivo del proyecto debería compartirles para buscar la solución?
Mientras tanto, comparto el `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cens15</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
 
   {
     path:'home',
     loadChildren:()=>import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m=>m.HomeModule)
   }
   ,
   {
     path:'users',
     loadChildren:()=>import('./pages/users/users.module').then(m=>m.UsersModule)
   },
  {
    path:'alumnos',
    loadChildren:()=>import('./pages/alumnos/alumnos.module').then(m=>m.AlumnosModule)
  },
  {
    path:'cursos',
    loadChildren:()=>import('./pages/cursos/cursos.module').then(m=>m.CursosModule)
  },
  {
    path:'materias',
    loadChildren:()=>import('./pages/materias/materias.module').then(m=>m.MateriasModule)
  },
  {
   path:'**',
   redirectTo:'home'
 },

]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Lo curioso es que en otro trabajo que tengo, lo hice de la misma forma (y lo hago, porque subo actualizaciones) y no estoy teniendo este problema.
Espero que puedan ayudarme.
Un saludos.

Comment: que servidor utilizas? por ejemplo deploy to tomcat 9 soluciona useHash:true -->https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/49ae1918-2313-4e2b-b3de-24d8788c0eac/y

Comment: si estoy entendiendo bien  a que te refieres utilizo Laragon (un equivalente a Wamp o Xamp) que a su vez levanta un Apache, ya había intentado el useHash:true, pero no solución el problema. Igual Gracias.

Comment: Si me refería a intertar lo que comentas te puede ayudar esto?https://qastack.mx/programming/51182322/whats-the-difference-between-base-href-and-deploy-url-parameters-of-angular

Comment: podes tener en cuenta esto no se si es tu caso ?si LocationStrategy en HashLocationStrategy esta en la lista de proveedores la url se ve asi www.pagina.com/#/ -->{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },

Comment: @nestdan Muchas gracias por el dato, al final encontré un repositorio casi actualizado, lo cloné, y levantó bien. Voy a tener en cuenta este comentario ahora al compilarlo y subirlo otra vez. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Si podes coméntame  que paso al final me interesa gracias